# Loading CDN that requires jQuery in Wordpress

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript

According to wpdevsolutions the correct way to load CDN javascripts in Wordpress is like this:

```
function theme_name_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'pushy', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pushy/1.1.0/js/pushy.min.js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

The question I have is what do I do if the script require jQuery to be loaded?

This does not seem to work.

`wp_enqueue_script( 'pushy', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pushy/1.1.0/js/pushy.min.js', array(), '', true );`

The console gives me: *Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined*

Most of the relevant answers here seem to be fairly outdated or incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it with jQuery like this:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pushy', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pushy/1.1.0/js/pushy.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Comment: How can I load the js in the footer?